# How to get maximum and minimum values using Lambda function over a list of key and value in C#?

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a list. KeyValue has 2 parameters. String Key and decimal Value.

```
public class KeyValue
{
    public string Key {get; set;}
    public decimal Value {get; set;}
}
```

```
data = data.Select(a => new KeyValue
       {
            Key = (string.Concat(a.Key.Select(e => Char.IsUpper(e) ? " " + e : e.ToString())).TrimStart(' ')),
            Value = a.Value
       }).ToList();
```

This is to fill in the key, values in the list "data".
How can I fill in values in this list [1st max. Value, 1st min Value, 2nd Max Value, 2nd Min Value.....]

Comment: Hi Shishank, Welcome to the StackOverflow. Basically your question is how to create new list with given pattern. Is that correct? If yes, then have you tried anything? Can you show us your attempt? If you faced any error can you add that to the question? It would be nice if you provide [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the same

Answer (score 2):

Replace `.ToList();` with

```
.GroupBy(x => x.Key, x => x.Value, (k, g) => new { Key = k, Max = g.Max(), Min = g.Min() } ).ToList();
```

This uses the overload of GroupBy that is:

```
GroupBy(
  property_from_enumerable_to_group_on,  //group by key
  property_from_enumerable_to_output,    //just emit values
  function_to_apply_to_output.           //g is a list of Value so it does min and max on them
)

data.GroupBy(x => x.Key, x => x.Value, (k, g) => new { Key = k, Max = g.Max(), Min = g.Min()).ToList();
```

You could even replace your Select with it if you want a bit of a perf boost; the logic you have seems to change PascalCase strings to Pascal Space Strings but it's not necessary to do it on a million strings before you group, it could be done on the 10 strings that arise from the group. Also if we use the overload of select that allows us to detect the index of the char we can avoid doing a replace on the first char which means we can avoid the Trim, so perhaps something like

```
data.GroupBy(
  x => x.Key, 
  x => x.Value,
  (k, g) => new {
    Key = string.Concat(a.Key.Select((e, x)=> x > 0 && Char.IsUpper(e) ? " "+ e : e.ToString())),
    Max = g.Max(),
    Min = g.Min()
 }).ToList();
```

If you're determined to unpivot this you can put the minmax in an array that you SelectMany:

```
data.GroupBy(
  x => x.Key, 
  x => x.Value,
  (k, g) => new {
    Key = string.Concat(a.Key.Select((e, x)=> x > 0 && Char.IsUpper(e) ? " "+ e : e.ToString())),
    Vals = new [] { g.Min(), g.Max() }
 }).SelectMany(g => g.Vals, (g, m) => new KeyValue { Key = g.Key, Value = m} )
 .ToList();
```

Comment: "{" are not closed used after "new" @Caius Jard

Comment: Just caught that one too, thanks for letting me know 

Comment: In the last solution, I am getting 'a' does not exist in the current context @Caius Jard

Comment: A local parameter x cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local parameter   @Caius Jard

Comment: First solution is giving error: "Cannot Implicitly Convert Type Systems.Generic.List<string key, decimal min, decimal max> to List<KeyValue>  @CaiusJard

Comment: You can choose a diferent nam for `x`, like `d => d.Key` if you already have an `x`. Regarding "cannot implcitly" ... Indeed, your KeyValue has only two props: Key, Value. How will you store a min and a max in that? Output of this is like `{Key: Hello, Min: 1, Max: 10}, {Key: Goodbye, Min: 2, Max: 20}` - Do you want them like `[keyvalueformin, keyvalueformax, key2value2formin, key2value2formax]` etc?

Comment: Yes I think so. 
Supposing the Values: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0
I just want to reformat the list in the format {key:"Hello", Value:"4.0"}, {Key:"GoodBye", Value: "1.0"}, {Key:"Hi", Value: "3.0"}, {Key:"Bye", Value: "2.0"}   @Caius Jard

Comment: Check the above format @CaiusJard

Comment: I don't really understand it, if I'm honest; all your keys are unique and have only one associated value. Did you mean we should do Max-Min to give the difference? Max is one value and Min is another value - how do you end up with only a single value after saying you want max and min?

Comment: I implemented that by sorting the List based on values using a Linq query and then used a basic for loop implementation.

Comment: Was it an exercise in wasting CPU cycles? Sorting is expensive compared to just.. remembering two values

Comment: I was not able to get the right result with that method. So I had to get the result anyway.

Comment: Still working on the right way to do it.

Comment: The right way is to have your key, min and max as an inseparable tuple, but you're determined to have a key value pair so I've added an edit that will unroll the triplet to a pair

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be solved in 2 steps.

1. Sort the List based on values using the linq query.
2. Using this method: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rearrange-array-maximum-minimum-form/
   I filled the maxmimum minimum in the list.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).